# How do I implement this type of OOP structure?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I want to build a nice API (C#) to make it easier for people to consume, I think I've seen this before and want to know how to do this:

```
MyNamespace.Cars car = null;

if(someTestCondition)
       car = new Honda();
else    
       car = new Toyota();

car.Drive(40);
```

Is this possible? If so, what needs to be done?

Comment: I hope you do not expect both cars to be driven based on that singular car.Drive method call. The variable names must be different for your Honda and Toyota

Comment: ok I changed the code to make it more accurate thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Interface Car
{
void Drive(int miles);
}

class Honda : Car
{
...
}
class Toyota : Car
{
...
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I'll remove mine

Comment: that should be interface ICar

Comment: @foson - I did that at first but changed it to Car so it would fit with his sample code.

Comment: @ocdecio.myopenid.com, Then change your class lines to use "Car" instead of "ICar" =]

Answer (score 6):

You could do this a couple of different ways.  You could declare an abstract base class or you could have an interface that your object implement.  I believe the "C#" preferred method would be to have an interface.  Something like:

```
public interface ICar
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    void Drive(int speed);
    void Stop();

}

public class Honda : ICar
{

    #region ICar Members

    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public void Drive(int speed)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Toyota : ICar
{
    #region ICar Members

    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public void Drive(int speed)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I see everyone is pushing interface / abstract base class changes to you.  The pseudocode you provided more or less implies you already have this in place.

I'll pose something else:

You'll want to create a "CarFactory" that will return a specific implementation of your base class / interface.  The Create method can take your test conditions as parameters so you create the correct car.

EDIT:  Here's a link from MSDN -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954600.aspx

EDIT:  See the comments for another link.

Comment: Based on the changes to his question, I think your answer is the best fit now.

Comment: Posting an example would be really helpful, because he probably hasn't dealt with factories before.

Comment: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx for an Abstract Factory Example.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class named Cars.  Give it the Drive method.  Extend that base class in your Honda and Toyota classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
  public interface Cars
  {
    public void Drive(int miles);
  }
  public class Honda : Cars
  {
    public void Drive(int miles) { ... }
  }
  public class Toyota : Cars
  {
    public void Drive(int miles) { ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting how some of us saw that as miles driven and others of us saw it as the speed the car was moving at.  A think we need a more complete functional spec. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the namespace, also see my comment in the question about variable names

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    public interface Cars {
        void Drive(int speed);
    }

    public class Honda : Cars {
        public void Drive(int speed) { 
        }
    }
    public class Toyota : Cars {
        public void Drive(int speed) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an abstract class called Cars with an abstract method called Drive(). Subclass it and add implementations.